# How do i handle oauth in Nuxt with a separate API server?

Tags: go, vue.js, nuxt.js

Currently I have two separate apps

1. Frontend (Nuxt)
2. Backend (Golang)

On the backend I'm using a third party library called [Goth](https://github.com/markbates/goth) and I'm using Facebook as the provider. Everything works fine on the backend but I'm confused on how to do on the frontend which is on the Nuxt side

So technically on the backend there will be two urls

```
 /auth/facebook

/auth/facebook/callback
```

Once everything is correct then I will get the object from facebook on the backend side which is the API written in Golang

```
 data: {
         RawData: {
             email: "john@gmail.com",
             first_name: "John",
             id: "123123",
             last_name: "Grave",
             name: "John Grave",
             picture: {
                 data: {
                     height: 50,
                     is_silhouette: true,
                     url: "https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=13123123&height=50&width=50&ext=1553079619&hash=AeTX5RW5K_avWLbI",
                     width: 50
                 }
             }
         },
         Provider: "facebook",
         Email: "john@gmail.com",
         Name: "John Grave",
         FirstName: "John",
         LastName: "Grave",
         NickName: "John Grave",
         Description: "",
         UserID: "123123",
         AvatarURL: "https://platform-lookaside.fbsbx.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=2312802522337124&height=50&width=50&ext=1553079619&hash=AeTX5RW5K_avWLbI",
         Location: "",
         AccessToken: "EAAIuR3NSCPwBAEcp2jskHuUCzdWLB97Aq99nCV5HuieVVz8xGfJ6exAZDZD",
         AccessTokenSecret: "",
         RefreshToken: "",
         ExpiresAt: "2019-04-19T15:52:59.895655+08:00"
     },
     status: 200
 }
```

Assume that everything is working fine on the backend.

The only thing that I could think of is calling it on the method (Nuxt side)

```
export default {
  methods: {
    facebookLogin() {
      window.location.href = `http://localhost:8080/auth/facebook`
    }
  }
}
```

This will just redirect to the

```
http://localhost:8080/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQAaq9GYcGAnQ9wUCDAd5BFRHxMRjqGFR0J6zjGtYpD-
```

What are the correct steps should I do to communicate with the backend OAuth API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hi @sinusGob you can use this the auth plugin of nuxt

See the docs.
https://auth.nuxtjs.org/reference/providers/facebook

Thanks.